# I cannot write getter and setter for protected attributes

Tags: kotlin

I have just started Kotlin, having learned Java before.

In Java we can create getters and setters for protected attributes. However, in Kotlin, I can only add getters and setters for private attributes.

How can I write getter and setter for protected attributes?

Comment: May help you: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Comment: Can you provide your code and explain what isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
protected val blah: Int
    get() = 2
```

Comment: I tried but when i tried to get this attribute from main function, i could not see this attribute

Comment: @PhucNguyen Then you need to learn about visibility modifiers. You can't access a `protected` member from the main function. Only the child class can access protected members.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad Thank you for spending your time, I can get the point now :D